# How to get schema of LDAP server by UnboundID?

Tags: java, server, ldap, schema, unboundid

I'm trying to get schema of In-Memory Directory Server by using UnboundID. 
For in-memory ds i used custom schema: before import from LDIF file i clear schema.

Code:

```
//...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //...
        InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig config = new InMemoryDirectoryServerConfig("o=DFAT");
        config.addAdditionalBindCredentials("uid=1000", "root");
        config.setListenerConfigs(InMemoryListenerConfig.createLDAPConfig("LDAP", null, 389, null));
        config.setSchema(null);
        InMemoryDirectoryServer server = new InMemoryDirectoryServer(config);
        server.importFromLDIF(true, "dump.ldif");
        server.startListening();
        LDAPConnection connection = server.getConnection("LDAP");
        assert(connection.getSchema() != null); // failed - schema null
        //...
    }
```